# API retrurning 500 and CORS error without even starting the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My web API crashes silently and I've got no idea why. So far I've got two controllers, one for registration which worked flawlessly until I've created the second controller.

The registration controller fails with 500 internal server error and instant CORS error saying my origin can't access the resource(I'm using Angular on a different origin). I know CORS is not the issue, because I've had it working earlier and the other controller works without any problems, and I've tried all sorts of tags enabling CORS to no avail.

My biggest issue is that it fails silently - no error message, no popup, it doesn't even get to the controller's constructor so that I could step by step identify where it crashes - it just  returns 500 without any information.

My guess at the reason why it crashes is that the second controller required me to create a new model inheriting IdentityUser so that I could extend it, but it's just a guess - it's the first time I'm touching ASP.NET Identity. I've got not idea whatsoever how to debug this issue...

I don't know where this issue comes from so I can't paste any code here. You can find the repository here: https://github.com/Marred/Informakcja it worked without any issues 2 commits back. I didn't mess with the Angular code since I've got it working so it's 99% a backend issue.

Comment: Why haven't u enabled cors for `InformationController`? I would suggest creating a `BaseApiController` which should inherit from `ApiController` and enable cors on it. Inherit all controllers from `BaseApiController`

Comment: Isn't app.UseCors("AllowAny"); in startup sufficient? InformationController is the one working, I think it's fine. The attributes enabling cors on AccountController are there only becasue I had no other idea what to do to get it working...

Comment: i think `app.UseCors("AllowAny");` in startup isn't sufficient. You have to mention it on the controller level. Have you tried what I mentioned above?

Comment: But a request to InformationController passes, I get the requested json, it's the account controller that I have a problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repository from Github and built the solution on my machine. As you mentioned the `InformationController` is working fine and the problem is with `AccountController`. It has nothing to do with `CORS`.

When I try to hit `api/Account/login` from a REST client i get the following error with a status code of `500`:

`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type x27;Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager '1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]&#x27; while attempting to activate x27;Informakcja_api.Controllers.AccountController&#x27;.Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)`

The data model in `SignInManager` and `UserManager` should be same as `services.AddIdentity` in `Startup.cs`.

Solution to your problem is, make the following changes in your `Startup.cs` file.

Change

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

To

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This will allow you to hit the `AccountController`. Hope this helps :)

One more solution would be to keep the Startup.cs as it is. Change the `Account Controller` to the following code.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

//Rest of your code

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer when I get back home and try It. Any idea why didn't it throw an exception when debugging?

Comment: While debugging it was unable to find AccountController because it was unable to resolve the data models. Have you tried the answer?